# Adding @Transactional to Testcase leads to not persisted entities in database

Tags: java, spring, transactions, junit4, spring-data-jpa

I have some testclasses which usually look as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public class SpringTestRunnerTransactionTest {
 // Some tests which involve inserting data in the db here --> No persisted entries but 
 // entries can be fetched in same transaction
}
```

which pass all my current tests (wich also include querying inserted data which has been inserted in the same testcase). However, when I inspect the database afterwards, there are no persisted entries. 
The same holds true when adding the `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation on top of a test method, i.e.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SpringTestRunnerTransactionTest {
   @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
   @Test
   public void test() {
     // Some tests which involve inserting data in the db here --> No persisted entries but 
     // entries can be fetched in same transaction
    }
}
```

However, funny enough, adding the annotation to some dummy method, finally the entries are persisted in the db. I.e. the following "works":

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class SpringTestRunnerTransactionTest {

        @Test
        public void test() {
            abstraction();
        }

        @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
        public void abstraction(){
            // Doing all the tests here works fine and the entities 
            // are persisted in the database!!!!!
        }
   }
```

Now I was wondering why this is happening. I assume that in the first case either the transaction is not committed or rollbacked but I don't see why. Or is there a general problem annotating testclasses and methods directly?

Some further information: I am using a SpringData JPA / Hibernate / H2 stack.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default transactions are rollback in spring testing. If you  want to commit use
`@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)` at class level or `@Rollback(false)` at method level.

see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations for more info.